# ReactJS workflow and how to capture a button click

Tags: reactjs

I'm coming from a visual basic background (don't fault me) and am having a difficult time comprehending the workflow of a ReactJS project as well as having difficulty processing a button click from a page.  This is what I have:

I have a webpack.config.js file which contains the following:

```
const { resolve } = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),

  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    publicPath: "/"
  },

  context: resolve(__dirname, "src"),

  devtool: "inline-source-maps",

  devServer: {
    contentBase: resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    publicPath: "/",
    historyApiFallback: true
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test:/\.css$/,
        use:['style-loader','css-loader']
     }
    ]
  }
};
```

I figured out that the line entry: resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.js"), specified the file what will be executed when I enter the npm start command from my command prompt.

This is the code that is in my /src/index.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import * as Redux from 'redux';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Home } from "./screens";
import "./styles/app.css"

const Index = () => (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home} />
      </div>
    </Router>
);

render(<Index />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I'm not sure what this code does (I have copied a previous reactJS sample program as a template for my current project) but I believe since it has an import { Home } from "./screens command, the /screens/home.js file is the next file to execute (at least that is what appears to be happening).

This is the code of my /screens/home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from '../components/Header';

//think of React components as functions
```

class Search extends React.Component {

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
      }  

    appFields = {
        appTitle_literal: "",
        appDescription_literal: ""
    }


    searchJRS = (props) => {

        //initalize these fields
        props.appTitle_literal = "";
        props.appDescription_literal = "Please be patient while we set up your app"

        function valuesToArray(obj) {
            return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { return obj[key]; });
        }

        //define the url of the WebAPI that will be called to return data
        let url = "http://ec2-54-70-8-113.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/api/homepage";
        const options = { method: 'GET' };

        //call the WebAPI.  This should return 2 pieces of data
        fetch(url, options)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(myJson) {
            setTimeout(function(){ 
            if (myJson == undefined) 
            {
                console.log("fetch failed")
            } 
            else 
            {
                //inspect the data that the WebAPI returned
                var newArray = [];
                newArray = valuesToArray(myJson);  
                props.appTitle_literal = newArray[0].product_title
                props.appDescription_literal = newArray[0].product_description; 
                //since the homepage has been rendered, find the DOM element
                //that will display the application title and set it equal to
                //the title that was returned by the Web API
                document.getElementById("appTitle").innerHTML = props.appTitle_literal;
                //since the homepage has been rendered, find the DOM element
                //that will display the application description and set it 
                //equal to the description that was returned by the Web API
                document.getElementById("appDescription").innerHTML = props.appDescription_literal;
                document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = "";
                //since the homepage has been rendered, find the DOM element
                //that will be in change of the viewable data and change the 
                //visibility of those elements to visible.  The initial view of
                //the page has these elements visibility: hidden so a clean
                //background is shown when the page first loads and is waiting 
                //for the data from the Web API to be retrieved
                document.getElementById("btnStart").style.visibility = "visible";
                document.getElementById("intro_page").style.visibility = "visible";
            }
            }, 3000);
        });
    }   

    render() {
        this.searchJRS(this.appFields);
        return (
            <Header title={this.appFields.appTitle_literal} description={this.appFields.appDescription_literal} />
    );
}
}

export default Search
```

This page runs, displays a clean background, then when the data is retrieved from the Web API, the data returned is displayed as well as the button at the bottom of the page.

I have a basic understanding (I think) of how this all works together.

Now, I am trying to figure out how to get a second page displayed when the user clicks on the button.  Or maybe I need to have a different set of  "rendered" when the user clicks the button.  Regardless, I tried placing a simple javascript function into all the *.js files just to see if I could capture the button click but I always get an Uncaught ReferenceError: enterApp is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick error.

My question is, first is my understanding of the workflow correct and second, how do I capture the button click to render a new page (or render a new set of ?)

Thanks